# Minecraft. Spigot. Python. Connection established, but "get" methods returns empty

Tags: python, minecraft

I have the problem with minecraft Api.
I ran spigot 1.16.5, spigot 1.16.5. From minecraft i connected to spigot server. All were Ok.
I had installed Pyhton 3.9 and mcpi (pip3 install mcpi).
So, i ran script:

```
from mcpi.minecraft import Minecraft
mc = Minecraft.create(address="127.0.0.1", port=25565)
pos = mc.player.getTilePos()
```

On third line code hanged on ~30 seconds, after i got error

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "D:\test.py", line 6, in 
> pos = mc.player.getTilePos()
> File ".....\minecraft.py", line 157, in getTilePos
> return CmdPositioner.getTilePos(self, [])
> File ".....\minecraft.py", line 56, in getTilePos
> return Vec3(*list(map(int, s.split(","))))
> ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

Please, help me. What i did wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved! I have forgotten install plugin RaspberryJuice